# Have Javascript modify web page to display initialization progress

Tags: javascript, initialization, progress-bar

I'm working on a web app that allows users to select items from a menu, then does some initialization based on the selections before displaying the main interface. Initialization takes 2-4 secs/selected item, so I want to display an indication of progress. I've tried using both innerHTML and a progress bar, but the browser's not showing updates to either until all initialization completes. I've whittled down to the page below. Interestingly, if I uncomment the line with the alert(), Firefox updates the page before popping up the alert, but Chrome, Edge, and Opera do not. What's the right way to do this?
--Thanks!

```
<html><head>
<title>Javascript progress indicator</title>
<script>
var SELECTIONS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'];
function ThreeSecondTask(taskName) {
  var targetTime = new Date().getTime() + 3000;
  while(new Date().getTime() < targetTime) ;
}
function WaitForOkay() {
  if(!okayPressed) {
    setTimeout('WaitForOkay()', 1000);
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById('barline').style = 'display:block';
  var selected =
    SELECTIONS.filter(s => document.getElementById('check' + s).checked);
  for(var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    var s = selected[i];
    document.getElementById('row' + s).innerHTML = '<td>Doing ' + s + '</td>';
    document.getElementById('progress').value = (i + 1) / selected.length;
    console.log(s);
    // alert(s);
    ThreeSecondTask(s);
  }
}
var okayPressed = false;
</script>
</head><body onload="WaitForOkay()">
<table>
<script>
SELECTIONS.forEach(s =>
  document.write('<tr id="row' + s + '"><td><input type="checkbox" id="check' + s + '"/></td><td>Selection ' + s + '</td></tr>')
);
</script>
</table>
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="okayPressed = true"/>
<div id="barline" style="display:none">Processing selections <progress id="progress" value=0></progress></div>
</body></html>
```

Edit: Got it working by replacing the loop in WaitForOkay with the additional function below. I'd love to know a more elegant way to accomplish this, but this will do if necessary.

```
function doTasks(tasks, total) {
  if(tasks.length == 0)
    return;
  var t = tasks[0];
  if(!window[t + 'Status']) {
    window[t + 'Status'] = 'Started';
    document.getElementById('row' + t).innerHTML = '<td>Doing ' + t + '</td>';
    setTimeout('ThreeSecondTask("' + t + '")', 10);
  } else if(window[t + 'Status'] == 'Done') {
    tasks.shift();
    document.getElementById('progress').value = (total - tasks.length) / total;
  }
  setTimeout('doTasks(["' + tasks.join('","') + '"],' + total + ')', 1000);
}
```

Comment: This blocks the thread: `while(new Date().getTime() < targetTime) ;`  If your tasks are blocking tasks then the UI won't/can't be updated until they're done.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with a task that does nothing but block the UI for three seconds?

Comment: @David This is a stand-in for the useful computation that's going on in the actual app. I'm not looking for the display to update while this computation proceeds, but I'd like the changes made by the loop in WaitForOkay to display immediately after they're made, before ThreeSecondTask is invoked.

Comment: If that’s going to involve long-running calculations then the page is going to be unresponsive while they run.  Is it possible to perform the calculations on the server and let the client await an AJAX operation for them?  Or perhaps split up the calculations into small isolated pieces which are individually run with brief timeouts with UI updates in between?

Comment: I think that what I'm looking for a way to hand control to the UI between invocations of ThreeSecondTask so that the updates get displayed. I could see restructuring this so that TST gets invoked via setTimeout(), which maybe would relinquish control long enough to allow the UI update?

Comment: setTimeout is what I’m thinking of too.  Even a fraction of a second timeout before the next operation would give the UI time to render and handle events.  It’s kind of kludgy, I’ll admit.  But the more granular you can make the calculations with timeouts between them, the more it will mimic an async operation.  Could still feel very jarring as a UX though.